# JSON parsing with {} in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am looking for the simplest answer to the given problem statement.

```
class X{
  Address add;
}
class Address{
 String str;
 String pincode;
}
```

The request is formed with x object as :

```
X:{
 add : {} //when none of the fields(str, pincode) present & they do not have any value
}
```

Now , I do not want to send address: {} in the payload.

Any JSON annotations will do this job?

I tried with `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include. NON_NULL)` but not helpful to avoid the field.

Comment: *Where* have you put the `@JsonInclude` annotation? Could you show a little more context?

Comment: I have kept 
class X{
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include. NON_NULL)
  Address add;
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Include.CUSTOM` to define a custom filter, which will use the `equals()` method.

Since `CUSTOM` will instantiate the object using the default constructor and use `equals()`, you can simply specify the value class itself as the filter, if it implements a sane `equals` method:

```
class X{
    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = Address.class)
    public Address add;
}
class Address{
    public String str;
    public String pincode;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Address address = (Address) o;
        return Objects.equals(str, address.str) && Objects.equals(pincode, address.pincode);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(str, pincode);
    }
}
```

Note that this *will* however produce `add: null` when `add` is null. To avoid that, you can put it into a real custom filter:

```
class X{
    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = AddressFilter.class)
    public Address add;
}

class AddressFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Address)) {
            return false;
        }
        Address add = (Address) obj;
        return add.str == null && add.pincode == null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try @JsonIgnore annotation

```
class X{
  @JsonIgnore
  Address add;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to ignore always. Whenever the subfields in address is null/empty , i want to exclude this field

Comment: Sorry my bad. you can use @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) annotation in your getter method
class X{
  Address add;
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
  public Address getAddress(){
     return add;
   }
}